# Need help turning off tooltip for a specific series

Tags: highcharts

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to accomplish two things

- I'd like to enable/disable tooltip labels for specific chart series. I would like to have tooltips disabled for the volume and candlestick series but have tooltips still enabled on the axis. How I can achieve this?
- I'd like to have a datetime tooltip on the xAxis and y value tooltip on the yAxis. How can I customize the format of these values that show up for the x and y axis tooltips?

Here is a visual example of what I am after with yAxis and xAxis tooltip values
[image: axisexample]

### The code:

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/drewscatterday/yrezphgc/11/

### What I've tried

- `enableMouseTracking: false` - disabling this turns off all tooltips and it also disables my crosshair
- `tooltip: {enabled: false}` - disabling this turns off all tooltips
- I tried using the tooltip formatter function as well but this still had no luck:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function (tooltip) {
        if (this.series.name == "AAPL" || this.series.name == "Volume") {
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        } 
    }
```

Thank you for anyone who takes the time to read this and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is called `crosshair.label`. You need to enable it both on `xAxis` and `yAxis` and disable the tooltip as you tried before (`tooltip: {enabled: false}`).

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.crosshair.label
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.crosshair.label

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0r9odckq/